# How to pass tableview cell as an argument and load the images only to the corresponding tableview cells she photo button is clicked in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

i ve got a custom tableview .i want to pass the tableview cell as a pramater to a function.I m using [cell.btnImages performSelector].while clicking the photos button it should load the images to the corresponding tableview cell .is it possible ?below is the code.when image button is clicked .i need to pass the cell as an argument...
  [image]

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"IpadTableViewCell";

IPadTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"IpadTableViewCell" owner:nil options:nil];
    for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects)
    {
        if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[IPadTableViewCell class]])
        {
            cell = (IPadTableViewCell  *)currentObject;

        }
    }
}

  [cell.btnImages performSelector:@selector(imageButtonClicked:) onThread:nil withObject:cell waitUntilDone:nil];


return cell;
}



-(void)imageButtonClicked:(IPadTableViewCell *)tblCell
 {
// opne image select dialog
CGFloat prevButtonXPosition = 17, pageButtonXPosition, pageButtonWidth = 120, pageButtonHeight = 130;

   for (NSInteger i =1; i<= 9; i++) {
    pageButtonXPosition = prevButtonXPosition ;
    prevButtonXPosition = pageButtonXPosition + pageButtonWidth;
    UIButton *pageButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [pageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(onClickImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [pageButton setFrame:CGRectMake(pageButtonXPosition, 5, pageButtonWidth, pageButtonHeight)];
    [pageButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i.png",i]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [pageButton setTag:i];
    [cell.scrollView addSubview:pageButton];
}

UIButton *add=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[add addTarget:self action:@selector(onClickAdd:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[add setFrame:CGRectMake(prevButtonXPosition, 20, 80, 80)];
[add setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"last.jpeg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[add setTag:0];
[cell.scrollView addSubview:add];

[cell.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(prevButtonXPosition +80, 40)];
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

}
```

Comment: why didn't you just call it directly? 
[cell.btnImages imageButtonClicked:cell]; 
if imageButtonClicked is defined in btnImages

Comment: i m getting error if i m to use [cell.btnImages imageButtonClicked:cell];....NO visible @interface for UIButton

Comment: what is btnImages?? post your imageButtonClicked: method??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined the imageButtonClicked method in your tableview class but your calling for it in cell.btnImages. You should implement the imageButtonClicked method in the class of btnImages or call on it in self instead of cell.btnImages. If btnImages is of class UIButton you should instead do this:

```
[cell.btnImages addTarget:self action:@selector(imageButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Or simply just implement the UITableViewDelegate method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: i made the IpadTableView cell global when i call [self imageButtonClicked]; the tableview is getting update...but if I'm to call the above  [cell.btnImages addTarget....] the control is coming to the module but not getting updated on tableview row..any guess?

Comment: what is btnImages exactly, is it a UIButton? In any case, the class of btnImages needs to have the imageButtonClicked method implemented if this code will work.

Comment: ok, now i'm with you. then have the imageButtonClicked return a cell. define -(IPadTableViewCell *)imageButtonClicked:(IPadTableViewCell *)tblCell and in your cellForRowAtIndexPath do:

cell = [self imageButtonClicked:cell];

doing this will is just the same as having this method directly in the rowatIndexPath method, you can do performSelectorInBackground if you don't want it to be evaluated directly.

Comment: simply move the code in imageButtonClicked to cellForRowAtIndexPath  and you're done...

Comment: i ve got a custom tableview cell where each row has got a button named as images...clicking the button should load images only to that cell...[cell.btnImages addTarget];becomes a mandatory thing to used..

Comment: yeah, so either you don't use the imageButtonClicked method at all but just have that code in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method. or the imageButtonClicked needs to return the cell that you have manipulated.

Comment: @user578386 did this work in the end? mind marking this answer as solved?